# MySQL : How to fill in empty data with custom text

Tags: mysql

I have the following data :

```
SELECT
   city,
   region,
   postcode
FROM
   AREA
WHERE
   city IN ( 'Jakarta', 'Jabodetabek' )
```

with the result :

[image]

I want the result like this

[image]

I've tried several tutorials, including here

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17832906/how-to-check-if-field-is-null-or-empty-in-mysql

but the result is the same as the first image

Comment: Why should 'Jakarta Timur' match either of those?

Answer (score 1):

You must convert your values list to rowset.

For example:

```
SELECT
   city,
   area.region,
   area.postcode
FROM ( SELECT 'Jakarta' city UNION ALL
       SELECT 'Jabodetabek' ) cities 
LEFT JOIN area USING (city)
```

This query will give NULL for the row for which there is no `city` value in `area` table. If you need some custom string literal then use COALESCE() function, i.e. not `SELECT city, ...` but `SELECT COALESCE(city, 'Empty') city, ...`.

---

Depends on MySQL version you may use another methods: ROW() function, JSON_TABLE() function, etc.